# tomcat webapp folder name is changed

Tags: tomcat, talend

I have been using this link .../org.talend.administrator-5.6.1/ to logon to an webapp that was deployed on a Tomcat instance. All of a sudden I am getting a 404 error message with this link. I stopped and restarted the Tomcat server but still didnt resolve the issue. I see a folder under webapps org.talend.administrator so I thought I will try .../org.talend.administrator. This URL is working fine however I dont see the contents in this app that I used to see before. So I am guessing the app is pointing to the wrong folder? As far as I know nothing changed on the server. Can someone help me how to find the old folder location?

Answer (score 0):

looks like the H2 database is corrupt. This is not a tomcat issue. Consider this is no longer an issue. thank you.